# osxfuse and sshfs on mac sierra. Error - mount_osxfuse: the file system is not available (255)

Tags: macos, sshfs, osxfuse

So this seems to have been discussed on stackoverflow but still it doesn't solve my problem and hence here is the question:

`1. Logged into mac NOT as a root user. But I do have administrative privileges.
 2. Installed Fuse for macos (3.7.1) (https://osxfuse.github.io/)
 3. Rebooted mac.
 4. Installed sshfs (2.5.0) (https://osxfuse.github.io/)
 5. sudo mkdir ~/mount (Location I want to mount the linux volume)
 6. sudo sshfs myuser@myserver:/folderToMount ~/mount
 7. Also tried: sudo sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa myuser@myserver:/folderToMount ~/mount -o auto_cache,reconnect,defer_permissions`

I get the following error:

`mount_osxfuse: the file system is not available (255)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I setup an SSHFS share? “OSXFUSE file system is not available” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309293/why-cant-i-setup-an-sshfs-share-osxfuse-file-system-is-not-available-error)